# iMacros extracts only the first character from csv

Tags: firefox, csv, mozilla, imacros

iMacros script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#text" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL1}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" KEY=13
```

Csv File:

Numbers
123
456

Hi, I am a beginner with iMacros. When I go to http://www.editpad.org/ and run the above iMacros script, it is supposed to grab each number from every row and input in the textfield on the site. The issue is, it only extracts the first character!

Output: 

1
4

**EDIT 1:** I Think it's the "CHAR=" TAG that's causing this issue. Is there any other TAG I can use? Unfortunately, I'm having to use the key-press method of recording because the tag-targetting method doesn't work in my case. Which is why I can't use the "CONTENT=" TAG, which I know works well for sure.

**EDIT 2:** I know that there's a CHARS TAG, but when I use that, only a white-space is extracted for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Only one character is extracted this way, but I came up with a workaround:

I split every digit into separate columns. (you can do this with tricks using notepad++. Simply copy a column from Notepad++ and paste into Excel)

Then I appended zeroes to the numbers with fewer digits, eg: 7 became 0007.

So in the end it looked something like this:

A  B   C   D
0  0    0   7
0  1    2   3

etc.

Then within the iMacros script, I used multiple keypresses, each time a different Column:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL1}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL2}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL3}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL4}}
```

That did it for me as it fulfilled the purpose of this script.

Answer (score 0):

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#text" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL1}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" KEY=13
```

Try this code. I replaced EVENT with EVENTS.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It doesn't extract anything at all. But, I came up with a workaround (Check my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the .csv is bad created.
With the script of @user1744228:

> 

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL1}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL2}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL3}}
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#text" CHAR={{!COL4}}
```

You can use this tool to create propper .csv files:
http://cetagram.co.nf/csv-file-creator/
It's a .csv file creator which puts the text in UTF-8 mode and creates out of it numbers or texts, which can be used for your macro

Answer (score 0):

Try this code replaced EVENT with EVENTS and CHAR with CHARS